# React Router Transition Animation wipes out old router to white background

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have implemented a react router transition for a slide up animation using ReactCSSTransitionGroup as follows http://recordit.co/Bm39Gxir9F

I am looking for a way to prevent the screen from turning white during the transition, i.e have the new router slide over the previous one. Is there a way to achieve that?

Here's my code

Layout.jsx

```
<Container className={css['sendcoin']}>
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={transitions} transitionAppearTimeout={1200} transitionLeaveTimeout={1200} transitionAppear={true} transitionEnter={false} transitionLeave={true} >
                <Route path="/send/:type">
                  <div className={css['senddiv']}>
                     <...>
                  </div>
                </Route>
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
</Container>
```

router.jsx

```
<Switch>
        <Route exact path='/sign_in' component={SignIn}/>

        <Route>
          <Container>
              <Route component={Authentication}/>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard}/>
              <Route path='/charge/:type' component={LayoutCharge} />
              <Route path='/send/:type' component={Layout}/>
          </Container>
        </Route>
</Switch>
```

transitions.css

```
.appear { 
    transform: translateY(500%);
    z-index: 1000;
}
.appearActive { 
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition: transform 1200ms;
}
```

Comment: How did you solve it? Would be great to see your solution.